# How to modulate from A minor to C minor?

Tags: theory, composition

I have one bar in a film score to go from A minor to C minor and have no clue how to do it! Plese help

Comment: This will probably be regarded as a dupe of your last question, which gleaned answers explaining methods of modulating from one key to another.

Comment: Because the keys and modes bear the same relationship, [Modulating from key Gm to key Bbm \[duplicate\]](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/42649/70803) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Depends a lot on the style you are going for. Am to Cm needs to flatten the E to Eb, which can lead to quite interesting progressions. A smooth transition could be achieved simply by an altered mediant progression resolving as plagal cadence:

[Am - Dm - E - ] Am - Fm - Cm [ - Fm - G - Cm ]